# after apt-get install phpmyadmin - where are the files and access?

Tags: 14.04, phpmyadmin

I have a ubuntu server, version 14.0.4 I believe, and I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

From /var/www/public/phpMyAdmin

(phpMyAdmin is a folder I created)

It installed correctly, however I was expecting to see the standard phpMyAdmin files located inside that folder.  So I am wondering:

1. where were the actual application files installed?
2. how do I access the phpMyAdmin UI?  (I was expecting to go to `myserver.com/phpMyAdmin/` and just log in)
3. is it possible I need to use another port like :2206 in the URL to get to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: did this answer your question? If so, please accept my answer. If not, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, this is the final step I was missing!

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf #or edit similar file based on your setup
```

In the .conf file add this line (at the bottom preferably):

```
# phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Alternately, you can create a file in `/etc/apache2/conf-available` called phpmyadmin.conf, put the above line in there, and then sym link to it in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`- but I did the first method.

Then restart Apache with

```
[sudo] service apache2 restart
```

Your setup may want you to use `httpd` vs. `apache2`

Thanks to this tutorial for your help:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: In a standard Ubuntu install this should have happened automatically via linking the file to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`. No config file change is needed then.

Comment: hmm.. good point but at least of my installation (Ubuntu 14.x 64bit), nothing was added or modified in `conf-available` or `conf-enabled`.  Hopefully this helps someone else.  I'll add that to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you can access phpMyAdmin from http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ If you replace localhost with `myserver.com`, it should work as well.

For more information about configuration check `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/README.Debian.gz`.

Comment: This does not actually work.  I've tried `apache2 -S` to see if it's listed as a virtual host, it's not.  In my case it would be http://192.168.33.10/phpmyadmin (or maybe phpMyAdmin?) but this doesn't work.